# What does the Socratic badge definition mean?

Tags: support, badges

**Socratic:** Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a positive question record

I don't exactly understand what this badge is awarded for. Its description is ***very*** vague.

- What is "well-received"?
- What does "on 100 separate days" mean?
- What does "maintaining a positive question record" mean?

Comment: Look up Socratic Questioning in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_questioning The jist of the badge is that you've asked good questions over time. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Asking days badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) and/or [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/254929), on MSE

Comment: You can find a more in depth definition of the badge here:

http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/159166

Comment: This badge is f***ing hard to get ;) !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Based on [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record) query on [data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow) the meanings of the terms are as
follows:

- *Well-received*: Question score is positive and the question isn’t closed.
- *Maintaining a positive question record*:

  Equation

  ```
    (sum(total) - sum(negative) - sum(closed)) / sum(total)
  ```

  yields over 0.5 for all your questions.
- *100 separate days*: Not included in that query, but basically count only one
  question per day.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that data.SE exists! Thanks so much!

Comment: In that case you should take a look at the [badge progress report link post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/143653#143653).

Comment: Luckily, the recent update shows the progress in your own profile view.

Comment: That is true. Though, some of the queries linked on that post are about content to go through to get certain badge, such as _find Revival candidates to answer_.

Comment: So if I get a negative score on one of my questions....I can't get the badge ever? Does it reset?

Comment: @Pureferret: The point is to have more non-negative scored questions than the negative scored (or closed ones). You can see this on the formula on my answer. If the result of that formula is positive, your question record is positive. And for this to be positive, you need to have more questions with non-negative score than with negative score or closed.

Comment: Ahh, I misread "positive for all your questions" as "positive for all your individual questions". My Mistake

Comment: @BenVoigt: Let me check if I understood you right: the equation can't be correct because the question record would be positive in case where user has only 1 question with positive score?

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you assume `total = positive + negative + closed`. Then, if `positive > 0`, the constraint `total > negative + closed` will be fulfilled. However, it's `total = positive + negative + zerovotes = nonclosed + closed`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh, now I got it. It is my bad, the average on that should be over 0.5 obviously since it can't be negative in any case. Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: This answer is wrong in two respects: first, "well-received" means a positive (non-zero, not non-negative) score; second, deleted questions are also counted against your positive question record. All of this information is available on MSE (see related links above).

Comment: @Air: Feel free to improve it then by editing. :)

Comment: Note the question record can be lower than 0.5, or even negative. Assuming all questions are negative and closed, `(total -negative -closed)/total = -1`.

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but: how does someone, knowing only about the Socratic badge, know that the [linked query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record) is the one that is used for that badge? For that matter, given that the ["Asking days badges"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) discussion gives a different formula, i.e. includes deleted posts as well as negative-vote and closed ones, are we even sure this is in fact the relevant query?

Comment: There's something wrong with that query. It says that my score on Meta is 0.6 which is greater than 0.5, but I still haven't earned the badge.

Comment: @DonaldDuck You missed the first half of the criteria. You don't have 100 questions, well-received or otherwise.

Comment: @tripleee I think that comment was about the Curious badge which only requires 5 questions (I didn't have that badge back then).